# Cubase (11, Pro) - Send the same MIDI signal to multiple Instrument Tracks

Tags: cubase

Wondering if anyone can help.

I’m setting on a very large template. Some of the VSTi instruments I want to map come as different plugins that are related. Think “Solo Violin Tremolo”, “Solo Violin Staccato”, “Solo Violin Pizzicato” and so on. They do not come in a host like Kontakt or EastWest’s where you can load multiple patches basically within a single instrument. They are actually different VSTi instruments, each on different track. Some groups are made of 10 instruments, some of 12 or more. I want to treat those groups of separated VSTi / tracks as a single instrument, so that I can write a single MIDI part, in a single MIDI event, but have some notes played by an instrument, some chords by another and so on, switching between them with Expression maps. Typically Expression maps let you change the patch or activate a key switch. I’m looking for a way to tell, via Expression maps, “Play this note with the VSTi on this particular track”.

I don’t know if what I’m saying makes sense. A quick example is Spitfire LABS Trumpet fields (it’s free and awesome LABS — Trumpet Fields). It comes as a series of 14 different patches. I have each of them running on its own instance of Spitfire LABS VSTi, each on its track, but they really are just articulations or variations of the same instrument, so I’d like to write a single MIDI part and have it played by the different instances.

any idea on how to do this on Cubase 11? Thank you so much!

Comment: Can the VST instruments that are on "instrument tracks" receive MIDI events from assignable sources? There used to be a thing called the VST instrument Rack where the instruments just sit without any assigned/dedicated/hardwired MIDI track, and IIRC, MIDI tracks had Sends where you could send the same events to multiple VST instruments sitting in the Rack. If that's the case that these "instrument track instruments" can only receive events from their own track, not other MIDI tracks, then you should use the Rack instead. Just guessing, switched to Ableton in 2008 and never looked back.